# Unrecognized name: _PARTITIONTIME

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to find the total number of partitions in a bigQuery partitioned table. I am using below query:

```
`SELECT
     _PARTITIONTIME AS pt, COUNT(1)
 FROM
     `dataset_name.table_name` 
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY 1 DESC`
```

I took a break from Bigquery for almost 4 months, and I remember this query used to work earlier. Am I missing something?

Comment: Check the details for your table in the BigQuery UI. It will show if it's a partitioned table.

Answer (score 2):

As @ElliottBrossard mentioned in the comments, `_PARTITIONTIME` is a pseudo column available on partitioned tables **only**. If your table is not partitioned, the query will not work.

You can find more information regarding partitioned tables [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables).

Comment: Specifically, it exists for tables that are partitioned by *ingestion* time. If you partition by an existing column in the data then `_PARTITIONTIME` will not be available to query

Answer (score -4):

This query works for me

[image: Result]

Please share your result and error if you need additional help

Comment: okay, its works but what do you have to do for work, append data and then ask for the column name _PARTITIONTIME?